# Search Function On Keyup With AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

For the first time ever I am trying to get a search function written. I am using a AJAX function to call the php file on key up. This is performing weirdly because it is changing the content in the content area but it is not the correct content.

I am also using ajax to load data from the table to the same content area. My goal is that when you search it replaces the data being viewed with the most relevant data based on the criteria you have provided by that last keyup.

This is my search form

```
<div class="form-group pull-right">
                    <input type="text" name="itemID" id="itemID" class="search form-control" placeholder="Search product number">
            </div>
```

This is the AJAX function,

```
$("#itemID").keyup(function (){
jQuery.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          async: false,
          url: searchPath,
          data: itemID,
          cache: false,
          success: function(html) {
            $("#productResults").append(html);
        $("#productResults").html(html);    
            $('#loader_image').hide();
            if (html == "") {
             $("#loader_message").html('<p>There were no results that match your search criteria</p>').show()
            } else {
             $("#loader_message").html('Searching... Please wait <img src="http://www.wuno.com/monstroid/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/LoaderIcon.gif" alt="Loading">').show();
            }
            window.busy = false;
          }
        });
});
```

And this is my php search query

```
    $sql=" SELECT * FROM wuno_inventory WHERE wuno_product like '%".$itemID."%' OR wuno_product like '%".$itemID."%'";
    try {
  $stmt = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}
if (count($results) > 0) {
  foreach ($results as $res) {
    echo '<tr class="invent">';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_product'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_alternates'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_description'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_onhand'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_condition'] . '</td>';  
    echo '</tr>';   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
url: searchPath,
  data: itemID,
```

to

```
url: your_php_address_file,
 data: {itemID:$(this).val()}
```

Comment: That is a variable holding the path to the file.php

Answer (score 0):

Change your searchpath with valid url address below

```js
$("#itemID").keyup(function (){
    var itemID = $(this).val();
    var url = 'your searchpath here';
    $.ajax({
        type  : "GET",
        async : false,
        url   : url,
        data  : "itemID=" + encodeURIComponent(itemID),
        cache : false,
        success: function(html) {
              $('#loader_image').hide();
              $("#productResults").html(html);    
              if (html == "") {
                  $("#loader_message").html('<p>There were no results that match your search criteria</p>').show();
              } else {
                  $("#loader_message").html('Searching... Please wait <img src="http://www.wuno.com/monstroid/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/LoaderIcon.gif" alt="Loading">').show();
              }
              window.busy = false;
        }
      });
});
```

Note : using queries like that may cause sqlinjection so be carefull with these sql statements '%".$itemID."%'

Comment: If that query is not good to use then would you mind showing me what you would suggest?

Comment: You can replace that variable with sqlsafe string with mysql_real_escape_string method or i suggest you to use store procedures

Comment: Ok thank you, After updating my code to your answer it is still not working. I am expecting for the populated data to be changed every time a keyup. The data is not even ordering as I type in more chars. To get this effect do I need to find a better search algorithm?

Comment: put console.log(html); before $('#loader_image').hide(); code to see what you get from ajax request and add error : function(a, b, c) { console.log(a); } after success callback to see if there is error

Comment: I am sorry I cant figure out where to add the things from your last comment.